# Using QSortFilterProxyModel to Transform Table to Tree

Tags: c++, qt

I have a situation where I have a table of data that can also be viewed as a tree. Specifically, it's a list of alphabetical items where I want the user to be able to flip between a table view with a single long list of the items, or a tree view where the objects are organized in folders named "A", "B", "C", and so on.

I'm pretty experienced with Qt and QSortFilterProxyModel seems the right way to go, but it's not clear how mapToSource should work when there isn't a corresponding index in the source. The items themselves will all have corresponding indexes in the source model, but the "A", "B", "C" etc. items will not. The documentation doesn't say anything about this. My only guess is that mapToSource should return an invalid QModelIndex in that case, but it doesn't say. If that's not valid, then I don't see any way to use QSortFilterProxyModel for this purpose.

Has anyone done this and knows what to do?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation doesn't say much because it's up to you. A model has full control over what data is available to its users. Just because it's a proxy doesn't mean much. You will want to synthesize the "folders" on the fly, and defer to other items in the base implementation of the proxy. You'll want to add just the aggregation functionality to the sort proxy, i.e. let the `QSortFilterProxyModel`'s code handle sorting, and then you add a small shim over it that adds the parent folder items.

Comment: That's sounds like a roundabout way of saying, yes, if the proxy model index doesn't map to the source, then it should return an invalid QModelIndex. Correct?

Comment: No. The invalid model index is only for the virtual root item. If an item exists, it must have a valid index. This has nothing to do with proxies -- it's a basic property of the Qt model architecture. Remember that the proxy's data-forwarding behavior is just a nicety. The proxy must still be a valid model with proper semantics, and the fact that you translate indices between the source model and your model is an implementation detail that changes nothing else in outwardly visible behavior of the model. I.e. to the consumer of the model, it matters not that it's a proxy.

Comment: But my question is specifically about mapToSource. I have a situation where my proxy model contains data that does NOT exist in the source model. mapToSource is supposed to return the model index of the data in the source model, but no such data exists in the source model. I'm asking a very specific question, and so far, it is not answered, although I appreciate the attempts.

Comment: If there's no mapping to source then you return an invalid index. Easy. But again: those methods interplay with `QAbstractProxyModel`'s implementation details and you'd need to read its code to understand what it needs. Those methods are not used by the users of the model.

Comment: "Those methods are not used by the users of the model." What methods? I'm talking solely about mapToSource, which is most definitely used by users of the model.

Comment: `mapToSource` etc. is not used by anything outside of the proxy model itself. Remember that the basic contract of a model doesn't know about proxies. It is `QAbstractItemModel*`. Anyone who takes that interface doesn't even get to see those methods. Certainly not Qt code. `mapToSource` and such implement non-virtual inheritance: **methods within the proxy's base class**, such as `index`, `data`, `setData`, etc. use `mapFromSource` and `mapToSource` to implement desired behavior, that you normally won't need to override, but you do need to provide the mapping.

Comment: By corollary, where the mapping doesn't exist, you can't rely on the base class's `data` and `setData`: you need to synthesize the non-mappable elements in those methods, and forward to base class's `data` and `setData` for elements with valid mappings. If you wish, you don't need to implement any of that and can set up your proxy directly on top of a `QAbstractItemModel` - but you will end reimplementing a few of the methods that the proxy classes provide.

Comment: mapToSource is a public method and is most certainly available to and useful to callers outside of the proxy model. Perhaps it isn't necessary to call it outside of the class definition, but that's a choice, I'm doing it that way, and it works perfectly well.

Comment: The use outside of the proxy leads to tight coupling with what amounts to an implementation detail. The method should be used at most by a viewmodel that aggregates data for a view’s use. The method is public indeed but that doesn’t change what good design is. Decoupling and cohesion are quite important.

Comment: Of course, but not what my question was about. Thank you for your time.